# Custom filters for Nunjucks in Browser

Tags: javascript, nunjucks

So I added just plain via script tag this script here.

```
var env = new nunjucks.Environment();

// async filters must be known at compile-time
env.addFilter('asyncFilter', function(val, cb) {
  // do something
  return "test"
}, true);
```

In my template I then have

```
{{ item.opendays | asyncFilter }}
```

The error I get in the Chrome console:

```
Uncaught Template render error: (node/yummy/www/js/templates/restaurant.overview.html)
  Error: filter not found: asyncFilter
```

Probably something really simple, but I just can't get it to work.

And here is the code I use for rendering:

```
 items = nunjucks.render(Config.rootPath + 'js/templates/restaurant.overview.html', {items: data});
```

Comment: Please update your question with the information contained in the ticket and the way you are rendering the template is missing. You need to use that `env` to render the template :)

Comment: sorry for this. Fixed this and added some more info. Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: As I mentioned before, may you use `env.render` instead of `nunjucks.render`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This did fix it :) Great. Just to make it the Stackoverflow way, are you going to post this as an answer, so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using the environment you just created and set up.

```
items = env.render(Config.rootPath + 'js/templates/restaurant.overview.html', {
  items: data
});
```

That is, `env.render()` instead of `nunjucks.render()`.

Answer (score 16):

If you use [configure](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api#configure), that will return you the environment on which you should add your filter:

```
var env = nunjucks.configure('views');

// async filters must be known at compile-time
env.addFilter('asyncFilter', function(val, cb) {
  // do something
  return "test"
}, true);
```

Then you can continue to use `nunjucks.render()`.

Comment: Unless the OP really wants a custom environment I guess